# TelecomManager Android

Tags: android

I am using this to get the phone no from sim,

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String simphonenumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but I get an error as :

```
'getLine1Number(PhoneAccountHandle) in TelecomManager cannot be applied to     0'
```

Also I am not able to access :

```
tm.getDeviceId();
tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Comment: Are you requesting permissions? What android version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared this permission in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

> The method you are using is the only one part of the SDK to do this,
>   and only works on devices where the number is stored on the SIM card,
>   which only some carriers do. For all other carriers, you will have to
>   ask the user to enter the phone number manually, as the number is
>   simply not stored anywhere on the device from where you can retrieve
>   it.

Comment: I have added the permission . Also its ok it the string returns null or empty , but the problem is , I am getting an error while writing the code and compiling .. i amanita able to build the project .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a PhoneAccountHandle as argument of `tm.getLine1Number();`

There is many way to have a phoneAccountHandle :

`PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle =  tm.getSimCallManager();`

or

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("package name here", "your connection service class here");
PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, "just a label");`
```

Then you can call `tm.getLine1Number(phoneAccountHandle);` but be aware of null pointer exception (if it doesn't find any number, it returns null).